# How to disable Markdown feature?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown, design

If I want to ask something like "Is it a List<String> or a List<Question>?" it gets printed as "Is it a List or a List?" which obviously doesn't make any sense.

I can surely replace < by &lt; and > by &gt; to present the question the way I want, but that adds that extra effort I actually don't want to put in and I also don't think about it everytime so I only spot it when I actually posted the question which adds the extra irritation to discover the need that your question needs to be edited.

Isn't there any tag/feature/option to disable Markdown?

Or better, just disable it forever (as every decent forum does) and only allow users to write HTML when posted in a certain tag, e.g.

```
[html]You <em>may</em> write <strong>HTML</strong> here.[/html]
```

Or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're discussing code items, would you consider using the inline code tags to describe them? EG, you refer to a `List<String>` and a `List<Question>`; without any extra effort (aside from two characters, one at each side of the formatted string), you can have exactly what you want with Markdown.

You simply wrap the text in backticks (on US standard QWERTY keyboards, that's under the tilde, just to the left of the 1: "`"). Done.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling Markdown, you should learn to use it properly.

> Is it a `List<String>` or a `List<Question>`?

If you know how to use Markdown, it is easy enough to format just about anything you wanna say.

[Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) is some more information regarding the Markdown editor.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, the backticks do the work nicely.

Posting the entire story in a code block as suggested by jjnguy makes no sense. It's not part of code, it's just part of a textual/paraphrased answer.

Comment: Actually, jinguy didn't do it all in a code block. He used a quote block, because he was quoting you, and used the exact same technique I did inside said quote block.